# Can "literally" correctly describe something presented as not being literal?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Not that I expect to find English used correctly in spam email but I recently received a message with the following subject line:

*This Literally “Scrubs” The Air In Your Home*

I'm willing to accept the use of the quotation marks as *scare quotes* to indicate that the product doesn't actually *scrub the air*. But is *Literally* actually being used correctly since, assuming that the product works as implied, it **would** literally *"scrub"* the air even if it doesn't literally *scrub* it? If so, would the following subject line have the same meaning as the original and also be "correct?"

*This "Literally" Scrubs The Air In Your Home*

I admit that it might be best to avoid both of these lines but I like them more than the way "literally" is so often incorrectly used.

Comment: Yes, it has taken the meaning 'figurative' recently.

Comment: See the article [Did we change the meaning of literally?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally)

Comment: I'm not really sure which of the existing questions to mark as a duplicate, [since we have quite a few regarding this subject matter](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=literally). I don't particularly like choosing a closed one, but it seemed the closest at a *cursory* glance and it tunnels into another open question. If your question is unique Zhora, would you please explain how in an edit to the question? [We prefer to lump like-subject matter together under a single question for organizational purposes.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: There are many written instances of [***literally killed me***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22literally+killed+me%22) that obviously *aren't* to be understood "literally".

Answer (score 0):

The word 'literally' is informally used just to emphasize what is stated.

**[Literally](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/literally)**
(sense 3, OALD)

> (informal) used to emphasize a word or phrase, even if it is not
>   actually true in a literal sense.